# How to make my discord bot do calculations

Tags: python, discord

Ok, so the title is  a bit confusing and I'm sorry for that.
What I am trying to achieve is a command so people who use my discord bot can find the range of a in game target. The way the sum works would be:`Height x 10 / (users input of mildots)`.
Is a sum like this achievable in python for discord? I'm new so I don't know if this is possible or not. I have seen commands to do a singular function like add A+B together but, no tutorials on more complex calculations.

I should add the way I want this to work, is by having the user type the mill dots i.e. ( 3.2) then having the bot do the rest of the calculations.

Summery:
Is something like this possible?
Where can I learn these kind of functions?

If anyone could  point me to tutorials or just any resources that might help me learn this function I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT**
To make this clear as possible, I am NOT asking for the code, nor am I asking someone to code this for me. I am asking WHERE I can learn a function like this, OR what the function may be called so I CAN learn to code something like this my self.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Hi, Klaus. so I have not tried anything at this point in time, mostly because I am very new to python and making a discord bot. I have been able to do basic functions like sending messages through tutorials. I have tried to google this Subject to see if there is any tutorials or anything, however I think because of my lack of knowledge I might not be looking in the right places.

Comment: I had to update the question, I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me. I'm just asking two things: is it possible to do? And where can I look to learn this kind of function?

Comment: Make a bot that can reply to a simple command, like hello, there are a ton of tutorials to show you that. Once you can do that, then its just as easy to accept an input and return the result of a calculation

Comment: Hi Chris! so my bot can currently take users input using `async def on_message(message)` then replying with the answer I wanted such as displaying ammo types or just data. As per my last comment I am trying to work out, is the sum that i want to do possible in python or am I aiming to high, and where can I learn this kind of function etc so I can code it my self

Comment: for anyone who is interested, I have used this :
      await message.channel.send (256.41*10/9).   Which is great because at least I know I can send the value. I just have to try to work out now how to take the users input and put it at the end of the calculation, along with how i would call this out. `256.41 * 10 / (users input)

Comment: Well the user input will be coming in the `message` variable. So cant you just use that in the calculation

Comment: Ok. So where can I learn more about this kind of function/ How can I learn more about this. The whole time I have been very kindly asking for advice on where to find resources so I can learn this. I'm unsure if I can be any more clearer than I have been or if my post and or comments are being disregarded. But from my post and previous comments, I am asking for directions or advice on what I SHOULD be looking for since my search has come up short, because I DONT know the function its self I'm unable to Google the function and learn  how it works etc.

Comment: [this](https://www.pythoncentral.io/multiplying-dividing-numbers-python/) should help you. Don't forget to convert the user input to float or integer before multiplying or dividing it.